# Windows Server 2019 Hyper-V Discrete Device Assignment (DDA) of a NVIDIA Tesla V100 to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Centos Guest: Not found

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-18.04, hyper-v, tesla, centos8

Does anyone have experience of using DDA to passthrough an NVIDIA Tesla into a linux guest on Hyper-V?  This setup works perfectly when the guest is Windows 10 and according to what I have read, this should be perfectly supported when using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Centos 7/8 as the guest operating system.  However the driver fails to detect the presence of the Tesla at install time despite it appearing on the virtual PCI bus.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A combination of installing the latest kernel (5.0.0-1028-azure or 5.3.0-26-generic) on Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS then shuting down the guest. Increasing the high MIMO to 33Gb with:

Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 33GB -VMName vm-name

And then restarting, fixed the issue.